# How to open a local shell script file in Safari using terminal

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I know we can open html in Safari using terminal:

```
open -a Safari index.html
```

Also works for .txt files:

```
open -a Safari "file:///Users/poudel/a.txt"
```

But, how can we open .sh, .py, .R or other programming files?

```
open -a Safari "file:///Users/poudel/a.sh" # does not work!!
```

**Demonstration  Safari > File > Open File**

```
Supported: .txt .pdf .html
Not supportd: all programming scipts
```

[image]

**System Info**

```
Safari: Version 12.1 (14607.1.40.1.4)
Macos Mojave: 10.14.4 
Computer: MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
```

Comment: Safari will open `.sh`, `.py`, etc. Maybe you are meaning "execute"?

Comment: @l'L'l, On my system `.sh` will not open in Safari, but `.py`, `.R`, `.c`. etc. will.

Comment: Try doing `chmod +x script.sh` and see if it opens then.

Comment: @I'L'l  I changed the file to executable, `chmod +x a.sh` and so on, but still can not open any of these files.

Comment: astro123 - What is your desired result? Is it to be able to view the content of `.sh`, `.py`, `.R` files within the Safari browser? Or execute `.sh`, `.py`, `.R` files via the Safari browser? Or something else?